# Capistrano: cap staging git:check - how to configure ssh path in git-ssh.sh?

Tags: ssh, capistrano3

I want to figure out how to set the path to ssh in `git-ssh.sh` file copied to the server by capistrano after executing the deploy command.

Actually the second line of git-ssh.sh looks like:

```
exec /usr/bin/ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$@"
```

I can not execute this command directly on the server. The following error occurs:

```
[5b4fcea9] /tmp/app.de/git-ssh.sh: line 2: /usr/bin/ssh: No such file or directory
```

After editing the ssh path to `/usr/local/bin/ssh` it works well but capistrano will upload this file every time calling cap staging deploy.

See my logs on pastie for more details, specially in the git:check part:
http://pastie.org/9523811

It is possible to set this path in my deploy.rb?

Thanks & cheers
Mirko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, i got it. :))

```
Rake::Task["deploy:check"].clear_actions

namespace :deploy do
    task check: :'git:wrapper'  do
        on release_roles :all do
            execute :mkdir, "-p", "#{fetch(:tmp_dir)}/#{fetch(:application)}/"
            upload! StringIO.new("#!/bin/sh -e\nexec /usr/local/bin/ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \"$@\"\n"), "#{fetch(:tmp_dir)}/#{fetch(:application)}/git-ssh.sh"
            execute :chmod, "+x", "#{fetch(:tmp_dir)}/#{fetch(:application)}/git-ssh.sh"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be hardcoded in capistrano source code [link here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake#L18).

Instead of changing capistrano source, why don't you create `/usr/bin/ssh` symlink on the server? So this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/ssh /usr/bin/ssh
```

That will create a `/usr/bin/ssh` symlink that, when executed, will run `/usr/local/bin/ssh`.

Comment: Is there any reason why the binary is hardcoded and not configurable?

Answer (score -2):

In your Capfile if you add the following line you can override the git tasks:

```
require 'capistrano/git'
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to answer the original question